# Complete proof of 1+1=2

Tags: reference-request, peano-axioms

I'm searching for the proof that

- Started from Peano's axioms
- Using modern symbols
- Detailed as possible

Could you give me a link to it?
Thanks

Comment: What are your definitions of $+$ and $2$?

Comment: Usual addition over the natural numbers and the successor of 1.

Comment: Cf. [Principia Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica)

Comment: Does it have a modern edition?

Comment: Proving this is like shooting with rockets on ants. We have defined $2$ as the successor of $1$ and basically this is the whole story. Addition of $1$ gives the successor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a lot to prove here. Either you *define* $2$ to be $1+1$, so $2 := 1+1$, or you define it to be the successor of $1$, so $2:=S(1)=S(S(0))$, where $S\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is the successor function. But the definition of $+\colon \mathbb N\times\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is a recursive one with $a+0 := a$ and $a+S(b):=S(a+b)$, so that
$$
1+1 = 1 + S(0) = S(1+0) = S(1) = 2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, starting from the Peano axioms define the addition as

$m+0 =m$ and $m+n'=(m+n)'$,

where $n'$ denotes the successor of $n$ according to the axioms.

Define $1=0'$, $2=1'$, and so on.

Then it follows that $1+1 = 1+0' = (1+0)' = 1' =2$. Done.